# How to properly import libraries that I downloaded via pip or conda?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to use "matplotlib" for a project and when importing it I get: "matplotlib.pyplot not resolved from source", then I tried to import pandas and I got something similar, how can I fix this?
I am using WSL, and I am in a virtual environment that I created in conda.

I want to use some libraries but they are not imported, even though I installed them with pip and it appears that they are there, it does not detect them.

Comment: Are you sure you are using conda's environment python? are you using vscode or jupyter?

Comment: i used vsc, and im triying to import it but stills give the module not found error

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not connected to the correct conda env in visual studio code.
You could check that by pressing " CTRL SHIFT P" Then press on Select Interpreter and select your created environment.

To check if matplotlib was installed in the correct environment you could try the following:

1. open anaconda shell
2. type "conda env list" ( to see all the environment created)
3. type "conda activate <name_of_your_environment>"
4. type "conda list" (to see all the packages installed in this environment"
5. check if matpotlib appears in the outputed list

More:
to open anaconda shell type "anaconda prompt" in the search of your os.